# next(err) not stopping execution

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I am create an authentication route for my backend API:

```
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const User = require("../models/User");

let router = express.Router();

router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, phone, password } = req.body;
  if (!(username || phone) || !password) {
    let err = new Error("invalid parameters");
    err.status = 400;
    next(err);
  }
  // XXX: Perhaps a better way to do this
  let params = {};
  if (username) {
    params.username = username;
  }
  if (phone) {
    params.phone = phone;
  }
  User.findOne(params)
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        let err = new Error("invalid credentials");
        err.status = 401;
        next(err);
      }
      user.checkPassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) {
          next(err);
        }

        if (!isMatch) {
          console.log("we get here");
          let err = new Error("invalid credentials");
          err.status = 401;
          next(err);
        }
        console.log("we also get here");
        res.send({
          token: jwt.sign(
            {
              _id: user._id,
              username: user.username,
              phone: user.phone
            },
            req.app.get("jwtSecret")
          )
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      next(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When passing in a valid username but invalid password I get the output:

```
we got here
we also got here
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ...
```

The error I presume is because `next(err)` is not stopping the execution flow and therefore a response is getting sent twice.

Why is `next(err)` not stopping the execution flow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `return` inside your function after you call `next(err)`.

`next(err)` stops future routing, but it doesn't stop execution within your own function.  So, you need to either be using if/else or return when you're done to stop other parts of your own function from executing.

Personally, I would uses promises for all my asnyc operations and not use a mix and match of promises and callbacks.  Then, you can just reject and funnel everything to just your one `.catch()` at the end.

But, if you're going to stick with your mixture of promises and callbacks, you can add `return` statements like this:

```
router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, phone, password } = req.body;
    if (!(username || phone) || !password) {
        let err = new Error("invalid parameters");
        err.status = 400;
        next(err);
        return;
    }
    // XXX: Perhaps a better way to do this
    let params = {};
    if (username) {
        params.username = username;
    }
    if (phone) {
        params.phone = phone;
    }
    User.findOne(params).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            let err = new Error("invalid credentials");
            err.status = 401;
            throw err;
        }
        user.checkPassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }

            if (!isMatch) {
                console.log("we get here");
                let err = new Error("invalid credentials");
                err.status = 401;
                next(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log("we also get here");
            let token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id, username: user.username, phone: user.phone}, req.app.get("jwtSecret"))
            res.send({token});
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        next(err);
    });
});
```

If you change your implementation of `user.checkPassword()` to return a promise instead of using a callback, then you can do it this way without mixing callbacks and promises:

```
router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
    function throwErr(msg, status) {
        let err = new Error(msg);
        err.status = status;
        throw err;
    }

    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        const { username, phone, password } = req.body;
        if (!(username || phone) || !password) {
            throwErr("invalid parameters", 400);
        }
        let params = {};
        if (username) {
            params.username = username;
        }
        if (phone) {
            params.phone = phone;
        }
        return User.findOne(params).then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                throwErr("invalid credentials", 401);
            }
            return user.checkPassword(password).then(isMatch) => {
                if (!isMatch) {
                    throwErr("invalid credentials", 401);
                }
                let token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id, username: user.username, phone: user.phone}, req.app.get("jwtSecret"))
                res.send({token});
            });
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        next(err);
    });
});
```

The `throwErr()` calls will all end up in the `.catch()`.

Comment: I'll accept your answer when able :). Is it possible to show an example where promises are used. I don't have a great grasp on them and would be interested to see how they can be used in this instance.

Comment: @dedmass - Which database are you using?

Comment: mongodb/mongoose. I think I'm using promises there. The checkPassword method though uses bcrypt.compare which needs a callback.

Comment: @dedmass - Where is the `checkPassword()` method of your user object defined?  Is that part of your own user object?  Or something built into mongoose?

Comment: Something I built into mongoose. I was following this guide https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/password-authentication-with-mongoose-part-1

Comment: @dedmass - I added another option that shows how you could do it if you changed your implementation of `user.checkPassword()` to return a promise instead of using a callback.  In general, if you're using promises in part of your function, you want all your async functions to use promises so you can leverage chaining and error propagation of promises.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!